# Is there exists a $y$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $f(y)=f(y+1) ?$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, graphing-functions

A function $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval $[0,2].$ It is known that $f(0)=f(2)=−1$ and $f(1)=1.$ Which one of the following statements must be true$?$

Options are $:$

1. There exists a $y$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $f(y)=f(y+1)$
2. For every $y$ in the interval $(0,1),f(y) = f(2−y)$
3. The maximum value of the function in the interval $(0,2)$ is $1$
4. There exists a $y$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $f(y) = −f(2−y)$

---

I try to explain $:$

---

Since the function is continuous, there must be point between $0$ and $1$ where it becomes $0$ and there must also be a point between $1$ and $2$ where it becomes $0.$ .

[image]

Option $(1)$ should be true at $y=0$.

> Can you explain in formal way ?

Comment: You're are right there there exists $y_0$ and $y_1$ such that $f(y_0) = f(y_1) = 0$ with $y_0$ between 0 and 1 and $y_1$ between 1 and 2. However, we do not know a priory if $y_1 = y_0+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let a new function $ g(y) = f(y+1)-f(y) $ defined in $y$ in $ [0,1] $. $ g(0) = f(1)-f(0) $ and $ g(1) = f(2) -f(1) = f(0)- f(1) = -g(0) $. As the function is continuous, and it changes sign. $ g(x) =0 $ for some $ x $ in $ (0,1) $. Option $ 1 $ is true.

Comment: Please try to use formatting

Comment: I'm new. Joined just 15 min ago. Sorry for bad formatting but i hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: @Manoj welcome to Math SE , and as you are new here I advice you to have a look to this  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference