# Proving there exists x,y in an interval with continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

So suppose we have $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and $f(0)=f(2)$.

Can we prove there exists $x,y$ in $[0,2]$ such that $|y-x|=1$ and $f(x)=f(y)$?

I want to start by considering $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

MY OWN SILLY THOUGHTS INCOMING:

Originally I tried proving $g(x)>0$ and $f(x)$ is an increasing function, was not sure how to proceed

if my thinking is right, our conclusion would say that $d(x,y)=1>d(f(x),f(y))=0$ and this would contradict the continuity of $f$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your silly thoughts.  Why would $f$ be increasing?  You know that $f(0)=f(2)$, so if $f$ increases at first, it would have to decrease later in order for $f(2)$ to not be larger than $f(0)$.  Also, how does $d(x,y)=1>d(f(x),f(y))=0$ contradict the continuity of $f$?

Comment: yes you're totally right about the first one, I was just looking through books and I saw so many lemma's defining intervals with strictly increasing continuous functions. My silly thoughts are like the scratch work of scratch work to be honest...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465254/is-there-exists-a-y-in-the-interval-0-1-such-that-fy-fy1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using $g$ is fine.

Just compute:

$g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$

$g(1)=f(2)-f(1)=-g(0)$

So, either $g(0)=g(1)=0$ and you're done, or you have $g(0)<0$ and $g(1)>0$ or vice-versa.

Now use the intermediate value theorem on $g$ to find $t\in (0,1)$ such that $g(t)=0$.

Comment: 17 seconds difference.

Comment: @martycohen, yeah!

Answer (score 1):

That is a good start.

If
$g(x)
=f(x+1)-f(x)
$,
then
$g(0)
=f(1)-f(0)
$
and
$g(1)
=f(2)-f(1)
=f(0)-f(1)
=-g(0)
$.

Since $g(0)
=-g(1)
$,
there is a value $x \in[0, 1]$
such that
$g(x) = 0$
or
$f(x) = f(x+1)$.

Comment: I accept this answer as well haha, even though the system won't let me. We know the truth marty~

Comment: That's OK. I have points to spare.

Comment: x should be open interval , rt ?

Comment: I don't think so because then we couldn't talk about g(0) and g(2).